# Как зафиксировать объекты при масштабировании

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: При зуме 125 и т.д.]

**Кусочек кода HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aos/2.3.4/aos.css" 
  integrity="sha512-1cK78a1o+ht2JcaW6g8OXYwqpev9+6GqOkz9xmBN9iUUhIndKtxwILGWYOSibOKjLsEdjyjZvYDq/cZwNeak0w==" 
  crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />       <!-- Подключение анимаций -->
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Д<span style="color: #B44545;">ЖКХ</span></h1> <!-- изменение цвета текста отдельной буквы "Д" -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mes" data-aos="zoom-in">
    <span id="messageSpan"></span>
  </div>

<div class="reg">
        <div class="form-box">
            <div class="button-box">
            <div id="btn"></div>
            <button type="button" class="toggle-btn tog-btn" onclick="login()">Вход</button>
            <button type="button" class="toggle-btn" onclick="register()">Регистрация</button>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    background-image: url(images/gh.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;            /* фон */
}
.container{
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
    margin: 0px 370px;
    color: #346FC7;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.color-txt{
    color: #B44545;
}

.mes{
    margin: 0px 1100px; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 42px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0%;
    top: 25%;
    right: 1%;
}

.form-box{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.6);    
    backdrop-filter: blur(5.5px);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 1.2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0,.2);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.toggle-btn{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: medium;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    left: 10%;
}

.tog-btn{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    right: 10%;
}
```

Comment: а в чём вопрос? что не получается?

Comment: При масштабировании текст плывёт в разные стороны, форма статична

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете использовать свойство `max-width` для ограничения ширины контейнера с текстом, чтобы он не плавал при масштабировании страницы. Чтобы форма двигалась вместе с текстом, вы можете добавить свойство `position: absolute` и использовать относительные координаты для ее расположения. Например, чтобы форма оставалась по центру страницы, вы можете использовать следующий код:

```
.form-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* остальные стили */
}
```

Это позволит форме оставаться по центру страницы, даже если вы масштабируете страницу.